# How to overlay roads layer on top of all layers in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, layers

I want to put roads layer (from any source, please recommend some..) on top of my KML polygons and base layer:

```
baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS", "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0", {layers:"basic"});
            map.addLayer(baseLayer);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: not with wms - try a wfs or wfs-t service http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setLayerIndex](https://web.archive.org/web/20150725230401/http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html) and [raiseLayer](https://web.archive.org/web/20150725230401/http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.raiseLayer).

Here are some [good examples](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/15238/2022).

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you know some online source where I can find world roads layer?

Comment: You can find this kind of data here: http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

Comment: @againstflow Not really, I use the default openstreetmap or google maps layer. the link drnextgis posted looks like it might help.