# How can I make a polygon feature selectable on the edges, but not in the enclosed area

Tags: openlayers

My map has markers in a layer and can select any marker by clicking on it. 
I also have a layer that contains polygon features, and I can also select these by clicking on them - either the edge or anywhere in the enclosed space.

When a polygon is over a marker, then I can't click on the marker - without hiding or disabling the polygon.

Is there a way to make the polygon feature selectable by clicking on its edges, but transparent to selection in the enclosed area?

Responding to comment from https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/56638/jbalk
This is a different question to [How to define layer order in Openlayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/how-to-define-layer-order-in-openlayers)  however, the solution to that question does point to a good solution here. If the markers are on top of the polygons, then I expect that the markers would receive the click events on the markers but the polygons would receive the click events between the markers. This is not the same as 'make a polygon selectable on the edges', but it would solve my issue. Does that make it a duplicate?

Comment: you could convert the polygons to lines and make the lines selectable and make the polygons Not selectable.  I haven't worked with openlayers so I'm just guessing. There may be a much better method.

Comment: That's not a bad suggestion, but looses the ability to fill the polygons. I hope there is a better method .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define layer order in Openlayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/how-to-define-layer-order-in-openlayers)

Comment: I think your question is actually about layer indexing.  See this post:  [layer indexing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/how-to-define-layer-order-in-openlayers)